# How to enhance the contrast using convertTo?

Tags: c, opencv

I am new in opencv c language. I need yo enhance my image contrast. i used the function

```
    cvconvertTo(imh,-1,2,0);
```

The problem is where should i use the input image variable?
 Please help me
 Thank you

Comment: please do **not** use opencv's deprecated c-api, but the c++ one (cv::Mat)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the OpenCV tutorial [Changing the contrast and brightness of an image](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html).

Given you parameters `alpha` (*scale*) and `beta` (*shift*), you can apply the transformation:

[image]

Given an input image:

[image]

you can change the contrast and brightness to get, for example, this:

[image]

You can do this with **C++ api** (recommended):

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    imshow("Before", img);

    double alpha = 2;
    double beta = 10;
    img.convertTo(img, -1, alpha, beta);

    imshow("After", img);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

You can also use **obsolete C api**:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("path_to_image");

    cvShowImage("Before", img);

    double alpha = 2;
    double beta = 10;

    cvConvertScale(img, img, alpha, beta);

    cvShowImage("After", img);
    cvWaitKey();

    return 0;
}
```