# Method that does the same as Mat.convertTo with IplImage? OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm applying contrast with opencv.
I follow [the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html) to make contrast transformation with:

```
for(int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++) { 
  for(int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++) { 
    for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
      new_image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[c] =
         saturate_cast<uchar>(alpha*(image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[c]) + beta);
    }
  }
}
```

But the contrast this method apply was not the one i want.
So then i found [this tutorial](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com.br/2011/11/track-bars.html) which uses:

```
Mat dst;
int iBrightness  = iSliderValue1 - 50;
double dContrast = iSliderValue2 / 50.0;
src.convertTo(dst, -1, dContrast, iBrightness);
```

but this uses Mat and for m work i'm doind IplImage.
How could i made it with IplImage? I tried cvConvert but it seems to not do this.

Comment: do **not** use IplImages for anything. the c-api is deadbeef

Comment: see second answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664187/converting-cvmat-to-iplimage

Comment: i was using as my professor lead me saind IPlImages were faster than mat and my work would be real time

Comment: your professor is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enhance the contrast using convertTo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840229/how-to-enhance-the-contrast-using-convertto)

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use

```
IplImage* img = new IplImage(srcImage);//where srcImage is cv::Mat.
```